# Подключить класс php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Проблема такая - стоит autoload, и классы из определенных папок подгружаются сами, все работало, но появилась задача сделать ajax запрос с БД, обычно за связь с бд отвечает специальный класс, который я периодический вызываю, но тут что то все пошло не так.

Файл php на который ссылается ajax (его код)

```
<?php

//include_once (ROOT . '/components/Db.php');

if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
    {
        $option = $_POST['get_option'];
        //$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shop;charset=utf8;";
        //$db = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');

        $db = Db::getConnection();

        $result = $db->query("select id,name from subcategories where id_parent=".$option);

        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            echo "<option value = ".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
        }
        exit;  
    }
?>
```

`Db:: getConnection()` - устанавливает соединение с базой

ajax не работал, из консоли я узнал что класс не найден

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in C:\Server\data\htdocs\controllers\select
.php:11
```

Решил подключить по старинке через include_once, но там появляется другая ошибка что по такому пути нет класса

```
include_once(ROOT/components/Db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
 in <b>C:\Server\data\htdocs\controllers\select.php
```

Как я понял он пытается найти класс в файле запроса , кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой ? По работоспособности кода - если закоментить вызов класса и раскоментить 2 строки предшествующие, все работает

**Доп.инфо**
**Файл Autoload**

```
function my_autoload($class_name)
{
    # Список всех классов в директориях в массив
    $array_paths = array(
        '/model/',
        '/components/'
    );

    foreach ($array_paths as $path) {
        $path = ROOT . $path . $class_name . '.php';
        if (is_file($path)) {
            include_once $path;
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
```

Подключить его тоже не получается

**Решение проблемы (Не понятно на сколько правильное это решение)**

Попытался подключить файл вот так

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once ($path.'/components/Db.php');
```

и он подключился, но тоже не понятно как, лог ошибок изменился. В ошибках было написано

```
<b>Warning</b>:  include(ROOT/config/db_params.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
 in <b>C:\Server\data\htdocs\components\Db.php</b> on line <b>9</b>
```

Класс Db прикладываю

```
public static function getConnection()
{
    $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
    $params = include($paramsPath);
    $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']};charset={$params['charset']};";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);

return $db;   
}
```

В ошибке сказано что он не смог загрузить уже файл db_params, заменив в `include ROOT` на  переменную `$path` которая `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` все заработало.

Непонятно только почему он вдруг перестал работать с ROOT

Comment: А по какому пути находится ваш Db.php ?

Comment: components/Db.php

Comment: Пробовали вывести ROOT  ? какой путь показывает ?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду в include написать root и проверить путь ошибки ?

Comment: Нет, просто вывести на экран значение константы ROOT , какой путь показывает ?

Comment: А чета я не наблюдаю в этом скрипте автолоадер. Или это только часть? По подробнее опишите как происходит процесс.

Comment: Я сейчас не имею доступа к пк , попозже напишу все точно , извините , автолоад в отдельном файле и подгружается сам при старте , структуру опишу позже

Comment: Просто сделай инклуд не самого файла, а **autoload.php**, он сделаем все сам за тебя.

Comment: @Arsen Путь ROOT верный >C:/Server/data/htdocs/<br />

Comment: @Darik Saifutdinov что бы я не пытался подключить он ничего не подключает

Comment: Видимо косяк с путями. Иначе объяснить эту ошибку нельзя. Кстати у вас инъекция на ровном месте, если кто-то узнает про этот файл, будет плохо базе. Рекомендую использовать единую точку входа и запросы обрабатывать именно на ней, чтобы они не были оторваны и не валялись как свалка, а также использовать экранирование при передачи значений в запрос или использовать подготавливаемые запросы.

Comment: @And Я использую подготавливаемые запросы к БД , тут что то не учел, спасибо